# Minimum number of observations needed to perform PCA or FA

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

I read in [this paper](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/203-30.pdf) (page 3) comparing principal component analysis (PCA) to factor analysis (FA) that both methods need a number of observations about 5 times the number of variables. Why? and how would you reduce the number of variables if you have few observations only?

Comment: I checked the link, and the recommendation there is clearly wrong. I have often eared 5 times the number of desired *components* which makes more sense: for example PCA is often used when there are more variable than observations....though you don't need to take either as gospel: these things can be tested.

Comment: The "5 time" recommendation is for FA only, and is very crude rule of thumb. As the data grows in size, the ratio may safely shrink. For example, with 20 variables I'd prefer 100+ cases, sure. But with 100 variables, 300 cases will suffice.

Comment: @user603, I've never heard of FA (not PCA) with n<p. I even doubt such algorithm exist or is needed.

Comment: @ttnphns: sorry I miss-read your comment.